# GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LFCDzs3 404 (Not Found) Socket.io Java Client

Tags: javascript, java, socket.io

I'm using socket.io java client https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Apparently, i've been stuck on this error ever since.

the following is my code:

```
socket = IO.socket("http://127.0.0.1:8000");
            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Successful");
                    socket.emit("foo", "hi");
                }
            });

            Socket sock = socket.connect();
            System.out.println(sock);

        }catch(URISyntaxException exception){

            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
```

the javascript part is the following:

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Hi! I am on");
  });
  socket.on('event', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log("Bye! I am off");
  });
</script>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What is the Exception you are getting

Comment: @me_digvijay Unfortunately, I'm not getting any exception at server side that's why cannot find out whether the problem is from javascript or java.

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed No I'm not running Node.js. I'm using socket.io java client